Trophimus left sick
Could it be possible that Paul's inability to heal Trophimus was because he was now unable to be used as a 'conduit' for God's Holy Spirit Power ?
Does his request for his 'cloak' to be brought to him from Troas suggest that his recent unenviable circumstances had changed him so that his reliance was no longer fully on God ?

2 Timothy 4:20 - Erastus has remained at Corinth, and Trophimus I left
sick in Miletus.


Where is your evidence that Paul had tried to heal Trophimus? If he had prayed for a healing without success, why assume that "spiritual failure" is the only explanation? Have you compared what Paul says about unsuccessful prayer in 2 Corinthians ch12 vv7-9?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group. Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  This question is not asking about a text but an unbiblical assumption that Paul could not heal.

Here is the complete list of places Trophimus is mentioned in the Bible:
Acts 20:4
Acts 21:29
2 Timothy 4:20
In none of these passages is there any evidence to support your questions.
Your questions are speculative - the forming of a theory or conjecture without firm evidence.

Could it be possible that Paul's inability to heal Trophimus was because he was now unable to be used as a 'conduit' for God's Holy Spirit Power.

In the absence of any evidence we can let our imagination go and arrive at many possibilities. Here are some examples:

Trophimus ate something that disagreed with him and Paul was letting nature take its course.
The Holy Spirit told Paul that Trophimus needed to endure his sickness like Paul had to endure his "thorn in the side" (2 Corinthians 12:7).
Trophimus was supposed to stay in Miletus and someone else was going to heal him.


Does his request for his 'cloak' to be brought to him from Troas suggest that his recent unenviable circumstances had changed him so that his reliance was no longer fully on God?

This theoretic question is based on 2 Timothy 4:13

When you come, bring the cloak that I left with Carpus at Troas, also the books, and above all the parchments.

It is conjecture - a conclusion based on incomplete information to say that Paul's request for someone to bring his cloak is an indicator of the status of Paul's relationship with God. Just as it would be conjecture to say that Paul must have had early onset Alzheimer's because he forgot his cloak, books and parchments.
It is always best to let the Bible speak for itself.
Where the Bible is silent it is best to remain silent or admit that we don't know.

Oh, my bad, soz
